# How to extract paths and response codes relevant to the path from swagger.yaml using java

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

This is the swagger.yaml file iam using

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "This is a sample server Petstore server"
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore YAML
  termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/"
  contact:
    email: "apiteam@swagger.io"
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
paths:
  /pet:
    post:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Add a new pet to the store
      x-swagger-router-controller: SampleController
      description: ""
      operationId: addPet
      consumes:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
          required: false
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
      responses:
        "405":
          description: Invalid input
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - "write:pets"
            - "read:pets"
    put:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Update an existing pet
      description: ""
      operationId: updatePet
      consumes:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
          required: false
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Pet23"
      responses:
        "400":
          description: Invalid ID supplied
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Pet23"
```

Config.class :

```
package Configuration;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Config{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("swagger.yml");
        System.out.println(inputStream);

        HashMap yamlMap = yaml.load(inputStream);
        for (Object o : yamlMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
        HashMap Paths = (HashMap) yamlMap.get("Paths");
        System.out.println(Paths);
    }
}
```

From this above java class we can able to print all the data under paths from swagger.yaml, but my requirement is to identify all the paths(ex: /pet) and response codes for each path and we also need to identify and store the reference path for each path/response.

Can some one please help me to achieve the above goals using java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using [`swagger-parser`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) v. 2.x instead of a generic text/YAML parser.

Comment: sorry , I don't have any idea on swagger, can u please elaborate your suggestion to achieve my requirements.